# Web page image with clickable areas that sends data to a server script and remains on the same page with no refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to have an image in a web page that can have clickable areas( like an image map in html) but I don't want to go to a different url when each area is clicked.

Rather I want some data value to be sent to a server whenever an area is clicked. Whenever an area is clicked I want to remain on the same page but send some data to a server script that will collect the data and process it.

After some clicks are performed I want a submit button that will finally take us to another web page to give the result. I don't know which language to use that can make all of these possible.

I am new to web programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Create your image map, but instead of entering the href attribute, make an ajax call that is bound to the onclick attribute for each polygon.

```
<area  alt="" title=""  onclick="alert('hello world')" shape="poly" coords="1100,132,956, .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript and .Click() method to achieve this. And also you can use the event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening.

For example:

Prevent a submit button from submitting a form
Prevent a link from following the URL

I am also new to web programming. But I hope it would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#clickableImg').click(
            $.post('page1.php',{ data1: 'value1'},function(data){
               // do something on successful post

            });
       );


   });
</script>

<img id="clickableImg" src="image.jpg">
```

and In your php file

```
//page1.php
<?php
  if($_POST){
      $data= $_POST['data1']; 
       // do other things here


  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! I got some idea on how to do it with javascript